# How to view uploaded files using git

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, version-control, repository

I have a remote server set up which I am using to store git repositories for website content and projects. I want to know if there is a way to use git but also view instances of these websites on the remote server for example /opt/git/ would display that current website or something similar...

Comment: The question you ask remains a bit unclear. Do you want to see remote branches of git? That can be done with 'git branch -r'.

Comment: What I want is when I have put all the files on the server using git I can actually see the files i.e. view the website

Comment: If you mean browsing the git repository, take a look at http://gitlist.org/